# R: Prevent melt from rounding to 2 decimals when reshaping tibble

Tags: r, rounding, reshape, reshape2, melt

I have a tibble (called *bidrag*) which i want to reshape using `melt(bidrag, id.vars=c("YYYYMMDD"))`.
However, this somehow results in all my values being rounded to 2 decimals and I need at lease 5.

```
> bidrag
# A tibble: 369 x 8
   YYYYMMDD `M:EUR:EFB:B` `M:SEK:EFB:B` `M:NOK:EFB:B` `M:GBP:EFB:B` `M:USD:EFB:B` `M:JPY:EFB:B` `M:Z60:EFB:B`
   <chr>            <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
 1 19900101        0.100         0.110         0.0200       -0.0200        0.250         0.110         0.200 
 2 19900201        0.150         0.0500        0.0100       -0.0700        0.120         0.0500        0.0800
 3 19900301        0.230        -0.0200        0.0300        0.180        -0.0800        0.110         0.330 
 4 19900401        0.100         0.0700        0.0300        0.0300        0.120         0.130         0.270 
 5 19900501        0.0100        0.0500        0.           -0.0500        0.130        -0.0400       -0.120 
 6 19900601       -0.0200       -0.0600       -0.0300       -0.170        -0.0900       -0.0300       -0.190 
 7 19900701       -0.0300        0.0300        0.           -0.150         0.220        -0.0100       -0.0900
 8 19900801       -0.150         0.0900        0.0100       -0.0700        0.320         0.0700        0.0200
 9 19900901        0.140         0.            0.            0.0700        0.0200       -0.160        -0.180 
10 19901001        0.0600        0.0800        0.0100       -0.0200        0.250        -0.100        -0.0800
# ... with 359 more rows
> bidrag <- melt(bidrag, id.vars=c("YYYYMMDD"), round = 5)
> bidrag
     YYYYMMDD    variable value
1    19900101 M:EUR:EFB:B  0.10
2    19900201 M:EUR:EFB:B  0.15
3    19900301 M:EUR:EFB:B  0.23
4    19900401 M:EUR:EFB:B  0.10
5    19900501 M:EUR:EFB:B  0.01
6    19900601 M:EUR:EFB:B -0.02
7    19900701 M:EUR:EFB:B -0.03
8    19900801 M:EUR:EFB:B -0.15
9    19900901 M:EUR:EFB:B  0.14
10   19901001 M:EUR:EFB:B  0.06
```

Comment: run `options(digits = 5)` in the console and then check `bidrag`. You can increase it if you need more numbers.

Comment: @RonakShah I have tried this and it still only shows two digits.

Comment: All of your values are 2 decimal places or less.  Why don't you edit in a test value with more decimal places to see what happens?

Comment: Ahh, that explains a lot. I didn't even notice myself. Thanks!